# Service Worker script persists in browser sources after unregistering it

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, service-worker

I need to completely remove the service worker script (sw.js) from my webpage; I can successfully unregister it via

```
// index.js
try {
    navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations().then((registrations) => {
        for (let registration of registrations) {
            // console.log('Reg:')
            // console.log(registration)

            if (registration.scope.endsWith('/my_scope/')) {
                registration.unregister().then((unregRes => {
                    if (unregRes) {
                        console.log('Unregistration success');
                    }
                    else console.log('Unregistration failed');
                }));
            }
        }
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log('Service Worker unregistration failed: ', err);

    });
} catch(e) {
    swRes['error'] = e.message;
}
```

It says 'Unregistration success' without errors, but I still see sw.js in Chrome DevTools => Sources. In chrome://serviceworker-internals/, I see

```
Unregistered worker:
Installation Status: REDUNDANT
Running Status: RUNNING
Fetch handler existence: DOES_NOT_EXIST
Fetch handler type: NO_HANDLER
Script: https://my.site/my_scope/sw.js
Version ID: 577
Renderer process ID: 11084
Renderer thread ID: 4
DevTools agent route ID: 18
```

I can stop sw.js in chrome://serviceworker-internals/ by clicking the Stop button, and the file goes away from Sources, but I need automated file removal due to project requirements.

I feel like Running Status: RUNNING restricts me from removing my worker, but I don't know how to change this status. Also I tried self-destroying worker from https://github.com/NekR/self-destroying-sw , but the behavior stays the same.

Any explanations of how to automatically remove SW's file from the browser storage are welcome.

*Upd:* Running Status is RUNNING only if I access my page with opened Chrome DevTools; otherwise sw.js appears in chrome://serviceworker-internals/ with Running Status: STOPPED and is flushed from Source tab.

Comment: Could it be that the service worker is actually reinitialized when revisiting the page?

Comment: @Wilt , it doesn't go away after execution even if I clear all browser caches and visit the page only once. The worker is registered, successfully ran, unregistered but not removed completely from browser, that's the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that unregistered SW's RUNNING status is an issue of chrome://serviceworker-internals/ tab; if I check the Application DevTools tab after accessing my page with DevTools open, I see my service worker deleted:

[Application tab with deleted SW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VA3b1.png)

So, the service worker is actually deleted after unregistration, but Chrome keeps it in DevTools for debug purposes, I suppose.